# STL std::remove_copy

Tags: c++, stl

```
 std::remove_copy

 template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class T>  
 OutputIterator remove_copy (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                               OutputIterator result, const T& val);
```

> Copy range removing value, Copies the elements in the range
>   [first,last) to the range beginning at result, except those elements
>   that compare equal to val. The output container must be large enough
>   to hold the result.

q1. **Why the size of the output  container must be large enough to hold the result? Wont the container grow by itself?**

q2. **Why is the previous content in  the output container  overwritten when i perform a remove_copy?** i.e When i perform a `remove_copy(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),' ');` The previous content inside the container b are lost and they are replaced by the new contents why is it so? Why is the result of remove_copy not appended at the beginning of  the output container?

Comment: The function is designed to work with STL container classes as well as with raw arrays.

Comment: Use [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) if you want the container to grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the size of the output container must be large enough to hold the
>   result? Wont the container grow by itself?

No. How could it? All the algorithm has is iterators, and you can't access a container's member functions (which would be required in order to grow the container) from its iterators. However, there are special purpose iterators which do know how to grow a container. [`std::front_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/front_insert_iterator), [`std::back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator), and [`std::insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator), which hold references to a container and call `push_front`, `push_back` and `insert` respectively whenever they are dereferenced and assigned to.

> Why is the previous content in the output container overwritten when i
>   perform a remove_copy?

Because that's just how the algorithm works. That's how all the standard library algorithms work. They don't know anything about containers. Not all iterators come from containers. And not all containers are even growable. If you want to append to the container, then use `std::back_insert_iterator`, as mentioned above. You can use the [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) helper function to conveniently create one without having to specify the template parameters. For example:

```
std::remove_copy(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(dest), value);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why the size of the output container must be large enough to hold the
>   result? Wont the container grow by itself?

Algorithms operate on **sequences**. Containers are one way of creating sequences, but they are not the only way. So, yes, a container could be written to grow whenever you access off the end, but sequences do not, in general, do that.

If you have a container you can use [`std::inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) to create an output iterator that expands the container as needed.

> Why is the previous content in the output container overwritten when i
>   perform a remove_copy?

It might be, or it might not be, depending on what the output iterator does. If it’s an iterator into a container (and not an insert_iterator), it only has access to elements that already exist, so it has to overwrite them. If it’s an iterator into an output stream it just writes elements to the stream; nothing gets overwritten.